# Cannot resolve sub-modules with webpack

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, signalr

I currently try to get the `@microsoft/signalr` npm package running with webpack and importing the module with `import * as signalR from '@microsoft/signalr'`. I get this error message which to my understanding boils down to webpack not being able to resolve the module-internal paths since all "missing" modules are part of signalr (I don't know how to call them). Running webpack shows this:

#### Log

```
assets by status 271 KiB [cached] 2 assets
orphan modules 589 KiB [orphan] 558 modules
runtime modules 937 bytes 4 modules
cacheable modules 598 KiB
  modules by path ./src/ 589 KiB
    ./src/ts/index.ts + 558 modules 589 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./src/scss/style.scss 376 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/scss/style.scss 301 bytes [built] [code generated]
  modules by path ./node_modules/ 8.23 KiB
    ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js 6.67 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js 1.57 KiB [built] [code generated]

WARNING in ./src/ts/app.ts 11:29-57
export 'HubConnectionBuilder' (imported as 'signalR') was not found in '@microsoft/signalr' (module has no exports)
 @ ./src/ts/index.ts 1:0-24 2:0-9

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value.
Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

ERROR in ./node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/esm/index.js 3:0-63
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Errors' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
resolve './Errors' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
  using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm/Errors)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Errors doesn't exist
      js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Errorsjs doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Errors.ts doesn't exist
      .html
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Errors.html doesn't exist
      .scss
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Errors.scss doesn't exist
      as directory
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Errors doesn't exist
 @ ./src/ts/app.ts 2:0-46 11:29-57
 @ ./src/ts/index.ts 1:0-24 2:0-9

ERROR in ./node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/esm/index.js 4:0-56
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './HttpClient' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
resolve './HttpClient' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
  using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm/HttpClient)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\HttpClient doesn't exist
      js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\HttpClientjs doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\HttpClient.ts doesn't exist
      .html
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\HttpClient.html doesn't exist
      .scss
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\HttpClient.scss doesn't exist
      as directory
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\HttpClient doesn't exist
 @ ./src/ts/app.ts 2:0-46 11:29-57
 @ ./src/ts/index.ts 1:0-24 2:0-9

ERROR in ./node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/esm/index.js 5:0-56
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './DefaultHttpClient' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
resolve './DefaultHttpClient' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
  using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm/DefaultHttpClient)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\DefaultHttpClient doesn't exist
      js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\DefaultHttpClientjs doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\DefaultHttpClient.ts doesn't exist
      .html
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\DefaultHttpClient.html doesn't exist
      .scss
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\DefaultHttpClient.scss doesn't exist
      as directory
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\DefaultHttpClient doesn't exist
 @ ./src/ts/app.ts 2:0-46 11:29-57
 @ ./src/ts/index.ts 1:0-24 2:0-9

ERROR in ./node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/esm/index.js 6:0-68
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './HubConnection' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
resolve './HubConnection' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
  using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm/HubConnection)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\HubConnection doesn't exist
      js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\HubConnectionjs doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\HubConnection.ts doesn't exist
      .html
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\HubConnection.html doesn't exist
      .scss
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\HubConnection.scss doesn't exist
      as directory
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\HubConnection doesn't exist
 @ ./src/ts/app.ts 2:0-46 11:29-57
 @ ./src/ts/index.ts 1:0-24 2:0-9

ERROR in ./node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/esm/index.js 7:0-62
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './HubConnectionBuilder' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
resolve './HubConnectionBuilder' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
  using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm/HubConnectionBuilder)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\HubConnectionBuilder doesn't exist
      js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\HubConnectionBuilderjs doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\HubConnectionBuilder.ts doesn't exist
      .html
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\HubConnectionBuilder.html doesn't exist
      .scss
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\HubConnectionBuilder.scss doesn't exist
      as directory
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\HubConnectionBuilder doesn't exist
 @ ./src/ts/app.ts 2:0-46 11:29-57
 @ ./src/ts/index.ts 1:0-24 2:0-9

ERROR in ./node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/esm/index.js 8:0-45
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './IHubProtocol' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
resolve './IHubProtocol' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
  using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm/IHubProtocol)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\IHubProtocol doesn't exist
      js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\IHubProtocoljs doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\IHubProtocol.ts doesn't exist
      .html
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\IHubProtocol.html doesn't exist
      .scss
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\IHubProtocol.scss doesn't exist
      as directory
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\IHubProtocol doesn't exist
 @ ./src/ts/app.ts 2:0-46 11:29-57
 @ ./src/ts/index.ts 1:0-24 2:0-9

ERROR in ./node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/esm/index.js 9:0-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './ILogger' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
resolve './ILogger' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
  using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm/ILogger)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\ILogger doesn't exist
      js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\ILoggerjs doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\ILogger.ts doesn't exist
      .html
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\ILogger.html doesn't exist
      .scss
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\ILogger.scss doesn't exist
      as directory
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\ILogger doesn't exist
 @ ./src/ts/app.ts 2:0-46 11:29-57
 @ ./src/ts/index.ts 1:0-24 2:0-9

ERROR in ./node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/esm/index.js 10:0-65
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './ITransport' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
resolve './ITransport' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
  using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm/ITransport)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\ITransport doesn't exist
      js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\ITransportjs doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\ITransport.ts doesn't exist
      .html
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\ITransport.html doesn't exist
      .scss
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\ITransport.scss doesn't exist
      as directory
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\ITransport doesn't exist
 @ ./src/ts/app.ts 2:0-46 11:29-57
 @ ./src/ts/index.ts 1:0-24 2:0-9

ERROR in ./node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/esm/index.js 11:0-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Loggers' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
resolve './Loggers' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
  using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm/Loggers)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Loggers doesn't exist
      js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Loggersjs doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Loggers.ts doesn't exist
      .html
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Loggers.html doesn't exist
      .scss
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Loggers.scss doesn't exist
      as directory
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Loggers doesn't exist
 @ ./src/ts/app.ts 2:0-46 11:29-57
 @ ./src/ts/index.ts 1:0-24 2:0-9

ERROR in ./node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/esm/index.js 12:0-52
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './JsonHubProtocol' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
resolve './JsonHubProtocol' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
  using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm/JsonHubProtocol)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\JsonHubProtocol doesn't exist
      js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\JsonHubProtocoljs doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\JsonHubProtocol.ts doesn't exist
      .html
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\JsonHubProtocol.html doesn't exist
      .scss
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\JsonHubProtocol.scss doesn't exist
      as directory
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\JsonHubProtocol doesn't exist
 @ ./src/ts/app.ts 2:0-46 11:29-57
 @ ./src/ts/index.ts 1:0-24 2:0-9

ERROR in ./node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/esm/index.js 13:0-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Subject' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
resolve './Subject' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
  using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm/Subject)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Subject doesn't exist
      js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Subjectjs doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Subject.ts doesn't exist
      .html
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Subject.html doesn't exist
      .scss
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Subject.scss doesn't exist
      as directory
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Subject doesn't exist
 @ ./src/ts/app.ts 2:0-46 11:29-57
 @ ./src/ts/index.ts 1:0-24 2:0-9

ERROR in ./node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/esm/index.js 14:0-34
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Utils' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
resolve './Utils' in '__PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm'
  using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm/Utils)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Utils doesn't exist
      js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Utilsjs doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Utils.ts doesn't exist
      .html
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Utils.html doesn't exist
      .scss
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Utils.scss doesn't exist
      as directory
        __PROJECT_DIR__\node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\esm\Utils doesn't exist
 @ ./src/ts/app.ts 2:0-46 11:29-57
 @ ./src/ts/index.ts 1:0-24 2:0-9

webpack 5.21.2 compiled with 12 errors and 2 warnings in 9571 ms
```

## Things I already tried:

- Deleting `node_modules` and re-running `npm i`
- Changing the import statement to directly import the sub-modules like `import { HubConnectionBuilder } from '@microsoft/signalr/dist/esm';`

I am now at the point where I don't know what to google for anymore. My "important" project configuration:

#### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: ['./src/ts/index.ts', './src/scss/style.scss'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  target: 'web',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader',
      ],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    },
    {
      test: /\.ts$/,
      use: 'ts-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Awesome App',
      template: 'src/html/app.html',
      inject: 'body',
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['js', '.ts', '.html', '.scss'],
    modules: ['node_modules'],
  },
};
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
  },
  "files":[
    "./node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

#### package.json dependency excerpt

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/webpack": "^4.41.26",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.14.0",
    "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "extract-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "fibers": "^5.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "sass": "^1.32.5",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.15",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.21.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/d3": "^6.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.25",
    "d3": "^6.5.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I was right with the resolving-part. There is a single `.` missing in the webpack.config.js in the resolve options which has to be `extensions: ['.js', ...]` and not `extensions: ['js', ...]`.